# derivative of 2 dimensional integral

Tags: integration, derivatives

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}: (x,y,t) \mapsto f(x,y,t)$ a derivable function in every direction.
Define $\mathfrak R_{\alpha}(u,t) := \int_{L(\alpha,u)} f(x,y,t) d(x,y)$ met $L(\alpha,u) = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | x \cos(\alpha) + y \sin(\alpha) = u \}$ .

I want to calculate the following derivative:
$\dfrac{\partial \mathfrak R_{\alpha} (u,t)}{\partial u} $ but I have no idea how to take the derivative of it. Can someone help me ?